# How to catch invalid serlialized data input with types

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Even while `type MyRequest` requires the `ID` attribute the function `process` is able to declare the variable of type `MyRequest` even while the `ID` attribute is missing:

```
export type MyRequest = 
  {
    ID: string, 
    Name?: string
  };

function process(jsonData:string) {
  try {
    let data: MyRequest = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    return data
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error:", err)
  }
}

let jsonData = JSON.stringify( { foo: "bar" } );
let result = process(jsonData);
console.log(result);
```

How to edit the function `process` so it errors if the incoming string data doesn't contain the `ID` attribute required by the `type MyRequest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.parse` is a JavaScript function, your interface is TypeScript. JavaScript has no way of interacting with the interface at run time in order to enforce that all properties on your interface exist when parsing, so it cannot produce an error in the way you have your example laid out.

In order to do this, you'd need to have JavaScript checks that validate your parsed JSON matches what is expected. Something like

```
export type MyRequest = 
  {
    ID: string, 
    Name?: string
  };

function isMyRequest(json: any): json is MyRequest {
    return json && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(json, 'ID');
}

function process(jsonData:string) {
  try {
    let data: MyRequest = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    if (!isMyRequest(data)) {
        throw new Error('invalid jsonData');
    }
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error:", err)
  }
}

let jsonData = JSON.stringify( { foo: "bar" } );
let result = process(jsonData);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The solution requires 7 additional lines of code. Is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: You could inline the body of the `isMyRequest` function into the `if` and collapse the body of the `if` statement onto the same line: `if (!data || !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, 'ID')) throw new Error('invalid jsonData');`